# Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

AndroidStudio3.2 Canary14 fails clean-and-rebuild with the following error

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha14-4748712.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712.pom
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-osx.jar
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712.pom
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-osx.jar
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712.pom
    file:~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-osx.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-alpha14-4748712/aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-osx.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

Answer (score 267):

> Beginning with Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11, the source for AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool 2) is Google's Maven repository.
>
> To use AAPT2, make sure that you have a google() dependency in your build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google() // here
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha12'
  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // and here
      jcenter()
  }
}
```

> The new version of AAPT2 fixes many issues, including improved handling of non-ASCII characters on Windows.

Adding the repositories in the `buildscript` is not sufficient, you need to add it also in `allprojects`.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven

Comment: This fixed it for me -- I had `google()` in `buildscript` repos but not in `allprojects` repos. Much obliged.

Comment: Thank you! it is such a simple fix. It begs the question as to why the error message has to be so cryptic that recommended action wasn't included by default

Comment: [LarsH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423105/larsh) answer helped, one more point is that google() should be present on top of others too. Order also Matters here.

Comment: Is it also possible to build the project without the `google()` dependency?

Comment: You could download the artifact from maven and put it into your offline repository if you really wanted to

Comment: Adding `allprojects {...` does it!

Comment: Its worked for me. Its a great post. goolge() .I think repository files are download from google(). why not in jcenter()??

Comment: @Mahabubuzzaman Because google publishes its artifacts directly to maven, which google() stands for - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Comment: not working for me ... Does any other solution, please?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad this is the solution to the problem - maybe you're facing a different problem or didn't place the 'google()' repository in allprojects?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I got "org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find aapt2-windows.jar" error and i placed "google()" to allproject and buildscript repositories ... it's about two days that I'm searching for the answer, but none of them helps me

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad can you share your project?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska thank you very much, I fix the issue by upgrading Gradle to the latest version :)

Comment: Thanks, i got my old android projecr working again!

Answer (score 48):

Are you opening a very old project?
If so, make sure your app's build.gradle has:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

(That solved it for me anyways)

Comment: The important part is the "google()" repository dependency.

Comment: For me it was the order. I had `google()` but it was down in the list of repos. Moving it on top of the list of repos fixed the issue.

Comment: this should be accepted... (for opening old projects at least)... the key repository was google() and it can be placed either to app's build.gradle or rather in project's build.gradle under allprojects > repositories, where jcenter() usually already is

Answer (score 21):

Just add `google()` on your buidscript and allprojects then rebuild the project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // `enter code here`
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // `<-- here`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I am in Iran, and some of google's repositories are restricted in my location. When I changed my IP to another country, this problem was solved. It seems you may have an internet connection problem when this error happens.

Comment: actually i am using vpn but the problem still remind and i cant run the project!

Comment: That's interesting. I was using a VPN that tunnels to  **Netherlands** and  when I  tunneled it to US  it downloaded the aapt tools. What's going on?.

Answer (score 5):

Update your app's build.grade file dependency with the updated version of grade

```
dependencies {    
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'   
}
```

*Follow android studio suggestion* of the version to update to.
after your grade classpath update and re-sync your app.

After all this *restart your android studio*.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error message:

> Could not download aapt2-osx.jar
>   (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860): No cached version
>   available for offline mode

Even if I had defined all the necessary dependencies for my proyect, and the right configuration into my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

The error still happening, but this message gave me a clue of what was happening:

> No cached version available for offline mode

So I discovered that I was working offline, **you need to uncheck the "offline mode" then Android Studio will be able to download the necessary resources to create the project**.

[image]

When your project is working again, you can check again to work offlin.

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this issue by changing the "distributionUrl" in `android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

The default value was `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` and I changed it to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip` and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()  //导入旧版本项目时，一般来说该处依赖会在更改classpath中gradle版本是自动添加
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
       /*
        解决报错：Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-5013011.
        Beginning with Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11, the source for AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool 2) is Google's Maven repository.
        To use AAPT2, make sure that you have a google() dependency in your build.gradle file, as shown here:
        */
        google() //但是此处不会，需要自主添加
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem even with `google()` fix by change this lines

change this in `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
```

and change this in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

to this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a four-step process,

1. change the classpath in build.gradle to the desired version.
2. Sync Now
3. After it downloads all the files, you can delete the new and add the previous version in Gradle.
4. Sync Now

Answer (score 0):

[3 steps to fix it below within the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLkBa.png)

1. Gradle bar to the right
2. Toggle offline mode sign
3. Rebuild en enjoy!
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W3a6_xwGOo&

Comment: After having a "Could not resolve ..." error and Android Studio (or gradle plugin or whatever) suggesting to look at offline mode, I couldn't find it!  I had looked through the settings, and various gradle properties and settings files.   This offline mode symbol in the gradle bar on right did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to resolve it by updating "Android SDK Build-Tools" to the latest version.

In Android studio, Goto Tools -> SDK Manager -> Select SDK tools tab -> check whether any update available for the Android SDK Build - Tools (updated to the latest v30.0.0).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.gradle and remove projectRoot.name file

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunality non of the answers above was complete enough, however this work for me . Just make sure your build.gradel has all of the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // Check if this Google exists and is in the first
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // Check if this Google exists and is in the first
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are living in IRAN,
add the following parts to your gradle.properties file:

```
# HTTP proxy 
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<your_proxy_address>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<your_proxy_port>

# HTTPS proxy 
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<your_proxy_address>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<your_proxy_port>
```

replace <your_proxy_address> and <your_proxy_port> with your proxy information.

Answer (score -1):

you need to tape in the: build.gradle ()
and type google()
and this option do it in buildscript & allproject section

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Answer (score -1):

Problem happened to me when i opened my old project

Can be fixed by upgrading the tools gradle

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"

Answer (score -1):

**important**: **if your country is blocked by android related sites(you receive 403 from android related sites like https://dl.google.com/dl/android) , make sure you have a working VPN, you may wonder if it is important, but i assure you it is important**

after making sure you have a working internet connection, do the following steps

1. **make sure your android studio and gradle version are compatible**. check it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
2. check if you have these blocks in **build.gradle(project)**

   ```
   .
   .
   .
     repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }

   .
   .
   .

     allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
       }
   }
   .
   .
   .
   ```

after doing above steps, if the app can't be run, do the following

1. close android studio
2. delete gradle caches(ubuntu: home/.gradle/caches)
3. open android studio and let gradle build the project. then try to run the app(**it is important to have a working internet connection specially in this step, some proxies may get response from some sites, but get blocked on others and the build error doesn't show the correct problem**)

Answer (score -2):

if google() not fixied then
File -> Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle

Then Uncheck Ofline Work, Done.