# Could not download aapt2-osx.jar

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started with the android studio. I am facing an error

> "Could not download aapt2-osx.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971): No cached version available for offline mode"

After adding this line `android.enableAapt2=false` I am able to build the project but not able to run it on my phone(OnePlus 5).

I have also tried this "[Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0)" but it doesn't work.

Please Help...

Comment: I have tried it doesn't work

Comment: try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running offline mode. That's why this issue is arised. You need to disable offline mode from `Gradle` in Android studio.

In Android Studio you can make `Gradle` disable by removing check mark of offline mode option:

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build tools` -> `Gradle`

[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

> "Could not download aapt2-osx.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971): No cached version available for offline mode"

This means your gradle is working in offline mode. You need to uncheck offline mode and try to put `google()` repo as the **first** one for your `build.gradle`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839