# Unable to fix the gradle sync issue

Tags: android, gradle

While building the project I am getting this error

> No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.2-5435860
>   available for offline mode.

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
//    android.enforceUniquePackageName = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.miride"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 71
        versionName "5.1.0.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
//          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    annotationProcessor files('libs/pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:7.1.0'
    implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:9.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
    implementation files('libs/mpointsdk.aar')
    implementation files('libs/basesdk.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mProfileSDK.aar')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried every possible solution but unable to get rid of this error. If anyone is having any solution or suggestion then please post.

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290877/2383176

Comment: yes i have already tried this, my gradle version is 3.5.2

Comment: check the answer with 188 upvotes in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode

Comment: Gradle is in offline mode:

Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work".

Answer (score 0):

Its show your android studio not connect with internet.

Comment: It is connected

Comment: so use this .I think it will help you . Gradle is in offline mode, which means that it won't go to the network to resolve dependencies.

Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work".