# Android Gradle Sync failed: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: java, android, gradle, resolve

The error is the following:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode.
```

Comment: Try it File>Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 23):

It is a problem found in the new Android Studio 3.6 update. But it is basically not a problem. 
**All you have to do is the following:** 
To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode

Here are some screenshots:

1. [First go here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOf1N.png)
2. [Toggle this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiDBX.png)

Comment: This helped me I setup offline mode before upgrading to 3.6. Then when 3.6 opened the checkbox for offline mode was gone in Preferences menu. Thank you so much!

Comment: After Toggle offline mode, make a gradle sync it will tell you what to do in the rest.
Thank you for the help @Asif Iqbal

Answer (score 10):

I was going through similar issues last night, this is what worked for me :

Open the *build.gradle* file from your app folder, it should look similar to this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

add *google()* to *repositories* in -**buildscript** and -**allprojects**, just like here :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()       // here
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()      //and here
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In Android Studio, go to **File** -> **Project Structure..**   *[ shortcut : **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S** ]*

In the ***Project*** tab -> Android Gradle Plugin Version -> 3.6.1 **and** Gradle Version -> 5.6.4 |||

Last, under the ***Module*** tab, make sure the compile sdk version is > 14 (ie: 25, 28 or 29..)

Answer (score 5):

solution is to enable gradle as highlighted in below picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I opened an old project with Eclipse. For me, it helped to add the following in *build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    // order may be important!
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50285646/1097104

In addition, a few times I had to use *File* > *Invalidate Caches / Restart*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Latest version Chipmunk. Then this solution for you.

step 1. Open Gradle Setting and copy **gradlePluginPortal()**  and paste it in dependencyResolutionManagement below.

step 2. Change **RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS**  like this
step 3. enable **android.enableJetifier=true**

follow the above step then definetelly solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, cached artifacts or metadata may be causing issues. Try clearing the cache for your dependency management system and re-running your build or resolution process. In android studio, File-> Invalidate caches -> Invalidate and Restart.
If you've tried the above steps and are still facing the issue, close the android studio and open it then run your application it will work fine. (It's worked for me... Hence i have added it)

Answer (score 0):

This i my project issue

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

I have Resolve this problem
added one dependency library.

> implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

Answer (score -1):

The project that you are trying to build probably doesn't have the required SDK version. You can download it from the Android Studio within the "Preferences" dialog, under Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK. [Preferences Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdWY2.png).