# No cached version of android 3.6.1 available offline

Tags: android

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 available for offline mode.

I upgraded Android Studio to 5.6.1 and it refused to sync. It started when  I upgraded Android Studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463052/andriod-gradle-sync-failed

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio 3.6.1 you can't find offline mode in setting and you need to find gradle in View-> Tool Windows-> gradle and you  should press `Toggle Offline Mode` button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I m using android studio 4.0.1.I had the same issue so maybe I can help.u just need to turn off toggle button.
Click alt+shift+a. Then u will see that toggle option.
You can also go to view->tool windows->gradle
Then click gradle .now you can see the toggle.
See if toggle is in offline mode .if it is then just press the toggle again n sync .try this hope it will work.