# Add android dependencies manually to gradle caches

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I need to add android dependencies manually to gradle caches directory, as the gradle build can not get it but I can download it from my browser. This is the error:

```
> Could not find aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:7.0.4-7396180).
    Searched in the following locations:
        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/7.0.4-7396180/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx.jar
```

I manually downloaded aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx.jar file and put it in the following directory:

```
username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/aapt2/7.0.4-7396180/18ae77ce0ff3ba9da85e4674c2c92751cd1dc973/
```

I found the directory name: "18ae77ce0ff3ba9da85e4674c2c92751cd1dc973" from this command:

```
shasum aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx.jar
```

After this, I run the gradle build again, But I got the same error again and the build process tries to download the library and did not noticed that I have already downloaded it. Should I do anything else to let the build process know that this file is already downloaded?

Comment: ist this a duplicate of [stackoverflow: how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file)?

Answer (score 0):

1. [If this is not your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0).
2. > Should I do anything else to let the build process know that this
   > file is already downloaded?

   Try in your **build.gradle** append explicitly path to lib. For me
   it's look like this:

   Path to:

   ```
   AndroidStudioProjects/DiceRoller/app/build.gradle
   ```

   Source:

   ```
   dependencies {
           ...
           implementation files("~/Downloads/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx.jar")
       }
   ```

   Run:

   ```
   gradle clean
   ```

Comment: I want to add this library to gradle caches. I found that I should modify the binary files in username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.XX as well. But I don't know how yet.